# Subscription automatically refund after three days

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

when my users purchase a subscription, it is automatically canceled within 3 days. When I enter the google play store subscriptions section on the user's side, it says open the application to confirm the application, and when you click the open application button, it still gives the same warning when you check again after the application is opened.
My iap code is as follows,
'

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inapp_purchase/flutter_inapp_purchase.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../resources/environment.dart';

class IAPProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late StreamSubscription<PurchasedItem?> _subscription;

  FlutterInappPurchase get _engine => FlutterInappPurchase.instance;

  final List<IAPItem> _productItems = [];
  List<IAPItem> get productItems => _productItems;

  bool _isPro = false;
  bool get isPro => _isPro;

  bool _inGracePeriod = false;
  bool get inGracePeriod => _inGracePeriod;

  Future initialize() {
    return _engine.initialize().then((value) async {
      _subscription = FlutterInappPurchase.purchaseUpdated.listen((item) => item != null ? _verifyPurchase(item) : null);
      await _loadPurchaseItems();
      await _verifyPreviousPurchase();
    });
  }

  Future _loadPurchaseItems() {
    return _engine.getSubscriptions(subscriptionIdentifier.keys.toList()).then((value) {
      if (value.isNotEmpty) {
        productItems.addAll(value);
      }
    });
  }

  Future _verifyPreviousPurchase() async {
    return _engine.getAvailablePurchases().then((value) async {
      for (var item in value ?? []) {
        await _verifyPurchase(item);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<bool> _verifyPurchase(PurchasedItem item) async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      if (item.purchaseStateAndroid == PurchaseState.purchased) {
        if (item.productId != null) {
          _isPro = _productItems.map((e) => e.productId).contains(item.productId);
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (item.transactionStateIOS == TransactionState.purchased || item.transactionStateIOS == TransactionState.restored) {
        if (item.productId != null) {
          _isPro = await _engine.checkSubscribed(
            sku: item.productId!,
            duration: subscriptionIdentifier[item.productId!]?["duration"] ?? Duration.zero,
            grace: subscriptionIdentifier[item.productId!]?["grace_period"] ?? Duration.zero,
          );
        }
      }
    }

    if (item.transactionDate != null) {
      var different = DateTime.now().difference(item.transactionDate!);
      var subbscriptionDuration = subscriptionIdentifier[item.productId!]?["duration"] ?? Duration.zero;
      var graceDuration = subscriptionIdentifier[item.productId!]?["grace_period"] ?? Duration.zero;
      if (different.inDays > subbscriptionDuration.inDays && different.inDays < (subbscriptionDuration.inDays + graceDuration.inDays)) {
        _inGracePeriod = true;
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
    return _isPro;
  }

  Future purchase(IAPItem item) {
    return _engine.requestPurchase(item.productId!, offerTokenAndroid: item.subscriptionOffersAndroid?.first.offerToken);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  static IAPProvider read(BuildContext context) => context.read();
  static IAPProvider watch(BuildContext context) => context.read();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12qGB.png)